# Android get AttributeSet runtime from standard View

Tags: android, xml, view

Is it possible?
I know, how to do this in custom View.

But what about default widgets?

I will explain - I saw how Calligraphy library gets their `fontPath` attribute (with wrapping base context).

But this is made on activity creation.

What I want - to do this in runtime, in any moment.
For instance, I click on TextView, is it possible to get `fontPath` attribute from it right now?

Or, once xml was inflated, view has no more relation to it?

Comment: see LayoutInflater.Factory interface

Comment: @pskink, could you please give more details? How that Factory will help me, when I got TextView in onClick, for example?

Comment: ok, so in your activity call `getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this)` before calling `setContentView()` and override `Activity#onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` method